# С++ какие вредности можно получить от не инициализированных переменных?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, стандарт

C/C++ допускает использование неинициализированных переменных. Следующее выражение допустимо:

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(void){
   int x; // x is unintalized
   std::cout << x << std::endl; //correct, value is ...
   return 0; 
}
```

Я использую в своей программе подобный код, например, с пост-инициализацией:

```
void foo() {
  int x, y = 100, ...;
  for(x ^= x; x < y; ++x){
    ...
    // do something
    ...
  }
}
```

Как видите, используется выражение:

> x ^= x

которое приводит к обнулению значения переменной.

**Такой подход оптимален?**

cppcheck на подобный пример ругается:

> cppcheck: Uninitialized variable: x

Comment: Оптимален `for(int x =0; x < y; ++x)`. Да, результатом `x^=x` является обнуление, но ведь *в самом выражении* используется неинициализированная переменная, правда?

Comment: От неинициализированных переменных получается много проблем - от неправильной логики работы программы, до краха, когда неинициализированные переменные используются в качестве индексов и получается выход за пределы массива. Или использование неинициализированного указателя. Именно чтобы избежать этого, компиляторы дают предупреждение когда видят любую операцию (кроме присваивания) с переменной, которая до операции не была инициализирована.

Comment: а вообще всегда лучше их объявлять там и тогда, где и когда они нужны, тогда и поводов не будет не инициализировать. (не)Грамотный код и (не)грамотная речь имеют одну и ту же ассоциацию

Comment: `используется выражение x ^= x которое приводит к обнулению значения переменной.` Нет. Так как переменная `x` не инициализирована, то в выражении `x ^= x` происходит чтение неинициализированной переменной, что вызывает неопределённое поведение. Это означает, что стандарт языка больше не налагает никаких ограничений на поведение программы. Не гарантируется равенство нулю переменной `x`, не гарантируется неравенство нулю переменной `x`, не гарантируется, что программа не завершится аварийно, не гарантируется, что она вообще скомпилируется.

Comment: Посмотрите на такой код: `int val; val -= val; std::printf("%d", val);` В clang он [выводит вовсе не ноль](https://godbolt.org/z/5qrzMsf4n). Да, с xor clang вывел ноль, поэтому я и использовал вычитание, но можете ли вы гарантировать, что вариант с xor и впредь будет оптимизироваться не так агрессивно, как вариант с вычитанием?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заметим, что компилятор на неинициализированные переменные реагирует предупреждением. Что означает примерно "ты хорошо подумал? Если хорошо - так тому и быть".

Вы хорошо подумали и пришли к выводу, что `x^=x` обнуляет переменную `x`. Значит, так тому и быть, и вы можете проигнорировать это предупреждение.

Только почему именно так, а не

```
for(int x = 0; x < y; ++x)
```

как обычно (еще и с ограничением видимости переменной-счетчика циклом)? Чем ваш способ лучше обычной инициализации? Кстати, умный компилятор оптимизирует его в обычное обнуление — см., например, [тут](https://godbolt.org/z/b81WvMbGj).

Если же вопрос

> какие вредности можно получить от не инициализированных переменных

то массу, просто массу! :)

Например, в том же цикле с неинициализированным счетчиком — сколько раз будет выполнено тело цикла?... Выделение памяти, когда размер задается неинициализированной переменной — сколько будет выделено?

Comment: Спасибо за подробное изложение ответа. Пожалуй данный ответ согласовываю верным, "как мне кажется"

Answer (score 6):

Использование неинициализированной переменной есть UB, и может запутать оптимизатор.

Не надо углубляться в преждевременную микрооптимизацию. Если на вашей платформе выгодно занулять через xor, то компилятор сделает это сам.

Comment: Спасибо за изложенный ответ. Про то, что "оптимизатор" может "запутать" на не инициализированные переменные, не знал. Буду придерживаться к x = 0;